# Python ssh script loop problems

Tags: python, loops, ssh

I'm no programmer, but I try modify the following script.

http://www.networking-forum.com/wiki/Python_SSH_Script

I would like to make the script a bit more efficient. 
At the moment the for loop makes the script do a new login for each command.

I would like the script do one login for each device and run all commands with one output for each device.

Here is the for loop:

```
# This function loops through devices. No real need for a function here, just doing it.
  def connect_to(x):
      for device in x:
          # This strips \n from end of each device (line) in the devices list
          device = device.rstrip()
          # This opens an SSH session and loops for every command in the file
          for command in commands:
              # This strips \n from end of each command (line) in the commands list
              command = command.rstrip()
              ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
              ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
              ssh.connect(device, username=username, password=password)
              stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
              output = open(device + ".out", "a")
              output.write("\n\nCommand Issued: "+command+"\n")
              output.writelines(stdout)
              output.write("\n")
              print "Your file has been updated, it is ", device+".out"
              ssh.close()

  connect_to(devices)
  f1.close()
  f2.close()
  # END
```

Comment: bothered about indentation?

Comment: What modifications did you try?

Comment: Please cleanup your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the correct indentation found on your source check out the modifications below.  This was inspired from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6203877/157744).

**NOTE** I do not have a target to ssh into and test these modifications.

```
def connect_to(x):
    for device in x:
        # Connect to the target 
        device = device.rstrip()
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(device, username=username, password=password)

        # Open up a stream for the conncction
        channel = ssh.invoke_shell()
        ssh_stdin = channel.makefile('wb')
        ssh_stdout = channel.makefile('rb')
        output = open(device + ".out", "a")

        # Send all of the commands to the open session
        for command in commands:
            # This strips \n from end of each command (line) in the commands list
            command = command.rstrip()

            # send the command
            ssh_stdin.write(command)

            # Update the local log file
            output.write("\n\nCommand Issued: "+command+"\n")
            output.writelines(ssh_stdout.read())
            output.write("\n")
            print "Your file has been updated, it is ", device+".out"

        # Close the connection after all of the commands have been issued
        output.close()
        ssh_stdin.close()
        ssh_stdout.close()
        ssh.close()
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. No output file and no ssh connection from the script.

Comment: @user2737247 Where there any exceptions thrown?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. The script runs just fine, but no ssh connection is made and no output file is written.

Comment: @user2737247  Not sure whats going on then.  When I get back to a linux box I'll take a look at again.  Sorry I couldn't be of more use.  This might be a dumb question but did you do a copy and replace on the end of the file?  I left off the call to `connect_to_devices`.

Comment: Sorry my fault. Didn't include the "connect_do_devices". But it stil doesn't work. Sorry my fault. Didn't include the "connect_do_devices". But it stil doesn't work. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ssh_commands_2.py", line 100, in <module>
    connect_to(devices)
  File "./ssh_commands_2.py", line 87, in connect_to
    ssh_stdin.write(command)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/file.py", line 314, in write
    self._write_all(data)

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/file.py", line 439, in _write_all
    count = self._write(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 1256, in _write
    self.channel.sendall(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 796, in sendall
    raise socket.error('Socket is closed')
socket.error: Socket is closed