# Paramiko - python SSH - multiple command under a single channel

Tags: python, paramiko

i have read other Stackoverflow threads on this. Those are older posts, i would like to get the latest update.

Is it possible to send multiple commands over single channel in Paramiko ? or is it still not possible ?

If so, is there any other library which can do the same.

Example scenario, automating the Cisco router confi. : User need to first enter "Config t" before entering the other other commands. Its currently not possible in paramiko.

THanks.

Comment: Sounds like you may need an interactive session, which paramiko does support - does the following question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373639/running-interactive-commands-in-paramiko

Comment: Nope, i do not want an interactive session. Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, I do not mean a manual (human) interactive session - I mean automating an interactive command, which is what your example scenario is. I think this can be done in paramiko or pexpect.

Answer (score 0):

if you are planning to use the exec_command() method provided within the paramiko API , you would be limited to send only a single command at a time , as soon as the command has been executed the channel is closed.

The below excerpt from Paramiko API docs .

> exec_command(self, command) source code  Execute a command on the
>   server. If the server allows it, the channel will then be directly
>   connected to the stdin, stdout, and stderr of the command being
>   executed.
>
> When the command finishes executing, the channel will be closed and
>   can't be reused. You must open a new channel if you wish to execute
>   another command.

but since transport is also a form of socket , you can send commands without using the exec_command() method, using barebone socket programming.

Incase you have a defined set of commands then both pexpect and exscript can be used , where you read a set of commands form a file and send them across the channel.

Comment: Let me check the pexpect and exscript too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48377644/3337089) or this [page](https://daanlenaerts.com/blog/2016/07/01/python-and-ssh-paramiko-shell/)

```
import threading, paramiko

strdata=''
fulldata=''

class ssh:
    shell = None
    client = None
    transport = None

    def __init__(self, address, username, password):
        print("Connecting to server on ip", str(address) + ".")
        self.client = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
        self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.client.AutoAddPolicy())
        self.client.connect(address, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False)
        self.transport = paramiko.Transport((address, 22))
        self.transport.connect(username=username, password=password)

        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.process)
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

    def closeConnection(self):
        if(self.client != None):
            self.client.close()
            self.transport.close()

    def openShell(self):
        self.shell = self.client.invoke_shell()

    def sendShell(self, command):
        if(self.shell):
            self.shell.send(command + "\n")
        else:
            print("Shell not opened.")

    def process(self):
        global strdata, fulldata
        while True:
            # Print data when available
            if self.shell is not None and self.shell.recv_ready():
                alldata = self.shell.recv(1024)
                while self.shell.recv_ready():
                    alldata += self.shell.recv(1024)
                strdata = strdata + str(alldata)
                fulldata = fulldata + str(alldata)
                strdata = self.print_lines(strdata) # print all received data except last line

    def print_lines(self, data):
        last_line = data
        if '\n' in data:
            lines = data.splitlines()
            for i in range(0, len(lines)-1):
                print(lines[i])
            last_line = lines[len(lines) - 1]
            if data.endswith('\n'):
                print(last_line)
                last_line = ''
        return last_line


sshUsername = "SSH USERNAME"
sshPassword = "SSH PASSWORD"
sshServer = "SSH SERVER ADDRESS"


connection = ssh(sshServer, sshUsername, sshPassword)
connection.openShell()
connection.send_shell('cmd1')
connection.send_shell('cmd2')
connection.send_shell('cmd3')
time.sleep(10)
print(strdata)    # print the last line of received data
print('==========================')
print(fulldata)   # This contains the complete data received.
print('==========================')
connection.close_connection()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`parallel-ssh`](https://github.com/ParallelSSH/parallel-ssh):

```
from pssh.pssh2_client import ParallelSSHClient

cmds = ['my cmd1', 'my cmd2']
hosts = ['myhost']
client = ParallelSSHClient(hosts)

for cmd in cmds:
    output = client.run_command(cmd)
    # Wait for completion
    client.join(output)
```

Single client, multiple commands over same SSH session and optionally multiple hosts in parallel - also non-blocking.

Comment: This doesn't do what you think it does. This runs each command under a separate channel.

Answer (score 0):

I find this simple to understand and use. Code provides 2 examples with **singlehost** and **multihost**.  Also added example **where you can login to a second user and continue your commands** with that user.

More info can be found in here: https://parallel-ssh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html?highlight=channel#interactive-shells

```
from pssh.clients import SSHClient
from pssh.exceptions import Timeout
from pssh.clients import ParallelSSHClient
from pssh.config import HostConfig

def singleHost():
    host_ = "10.3.0.10"
    pwd_ = "<pwd>"
    pwd_root = "<root pwd>"
    user_ = "<user>"


    client = SSHClient(host_, user=user_, password=pwd_, timeout=4, num_retries=1)

    #####
    shell = client.open_shell(read_timeout=2)
    shell.run("whoami")

    # login as new user example
    shell.run("su - root")
    shell.stdin.write(pwd_root + "\n")
    shell.stdin.flush()
    shell.run("pwd")

    try:
        # Reading Partial Shell Output, with 'timeout' > client.open_shell(read_timeout=2)
        for line in shell.stdout:
            print(line)
    except Timeout:
        pass
    shell.run("whoami")
    shell.run("cd ..")
    print(".......")
    try:
        # Reading Partial Shell Output, with 'timeout' > client.open_shell(read_timeout=2)
        for line in shell.stdout:
            print(line)
    except Timeout:
        pass
    shell.close()

def multiHost():
    pwd_ = "<pwd>"
    user_ = "<user>"

    workingIP_list = ["10.3.0.10", "10.3.0.10"]
    host_config_ = []
    # HostConfig is needed one per each 'workingIP_list'
    host_config_.append(HostConfig(user=user_, password=pwd_))
    host_config_.append(HostConfig(user=user_, password=pwd_))
    client_ = ParallelSSHClient(workingIP_list, host_config=host_config_, num_retries=1, timeout=3)

    # now you have an open shell
    shells = client_.open_shell(read_timeout=2)

    command = "pwd"
    client_.run_shell_commands(shells, command)

    try:
        # Reading Partial Shell Output, with 'timeout' > client_.open_shell(read_timeout=2)
        for line in shells[0].stdout:
            print(line)
    except Timeout:
        pass
    print(".......")
    command = "cd repo/"
    client_.run_shell_commands(shells, command)

    command = "pwd"
    client_.run_shell_commands(shells, command)

    #Joined on shells are closed and may not run any further commands.
    client_.join_shells(shells)


    for shell in shells:
        for line in shell.stdout:
            print(line)
        print(shell.exit_code)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("singleHost example:")
    singleHost()
    print("multiHost example:")
    multiHost()
```