# Call linux ssh client with password through paramico connection

Tags: python, linux, ssh, interactive, paramiko

I am trying to connect to a Linux box using paramiko and from that session execute an ssh session to establish a reverse tunnel to another machine.

Using keyfiles works fine, but it's not an actual option, and connecting to the other box to establish the connection  manually also won't be possible.

I am able to connect to the machine and execute non-interactive commands, and have been successful in executing interactive commands as well. I am however unable to "trick" ssh into working interactively this way, by using the example found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203653/how-do-you-execute-multiple-commands-in-a-single-session-in-paramiko-python)

Any feedback will be appreciated.