# how to execute multiple lines using paramiko and read only their output

Tags: python, paramiko

How do I execute multiple commands using Paramiko and read the output back into my python script?

This question is theoretically answered here [How do you execute multiple commands in a single session in Paramiko? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203653/how-do-you-execute-multiple-commands-in-a-single-session-in-paramiko-python), but in my view that answer is incorrect.

The problem is that when you read the stdout, it reads the entire content of the terminal including the program that you "typed" into the terminal.

Just try it (this is basically a copy paste from the above thread):

```
import paramiko  
machine = "you machine ip"
username = "you username"
password = "password"
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(machine, username = username, password = password)
channel = client.invoke_shell()
stdin = channel.makefile('wb')
stdout = channel.makefile('rb')
stdin.write('''
cd tmp
ls
exit
''')
print stdout.read()
stdout.close()
stdin.close()
client.close()
```

So my question is, how do I execute multiple commands and read only the output of those commands, rather than the input I "typed" and the output?

Thanks in advance for your kind help and time.

Answer (score 2):

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
target_host = 'x.x.x.x'
target_port = 22  
target_port = 22
pwd = ':)'
un = 'root'
ssh.connect( hostname = target_host , username = un, password =pwd)
#Now exeute multiple commands seperated by semicolon
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cd mydir;ls')
print stdout.readlines()
```

Comment: create SSHClient object, and then call ''connect()'' to connect  to the local SSH server.Setting the host key policy takes one method call to the ssh client object (''set_missing_host_key_policy()''), which sets the way you want to manage inbound host keys or you can use paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()'' which will auto-accept unknown keys( not secure).Next we set hostname,password,target host and target post (22 ssh port).we call connect method with ssh client object and then call exec_command and pass the commands and store command output in stdout and at the end,stdout.readlines() to read  output.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing the commands you typed because the shell echoes them back. You can turn this off by running

```
stty -echo
```

before your other commands.

Another approach is to not invoke an interactive shell, but just run the commands directly, unless there's some other reason you especially need an interactive shell. For instance you could say

```
client.exec_command('/bin/sh -c "cd /tmp && ls")
```

If you want a shell but without a pty, you can try

```
client.exec_command('/bin/sh')
```

and I think that will suppress the echo too.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
# Explicitly provide key, ip address and username
from paramiko import SSHClient, AutoAddPolicy

result = []

def ssh_conn():
    client = SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())

    client.connect('<host_IP_address>', username='<your_host_username>', key_filename='<private_key_location>')

    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls -la')

    for each_line in stdout:
        result.append(each_line.strip('\n'))
    
    client.close()

ssh_conn()


for each_line in result:
    print(each_line.strip())
```