# paramiko print exec_command result immediately

Tags: python, ssh, stream, paramiko

I know `exec_command` returns 3 streams, but I'm unable to print the output as it should arrive to these streams.

```
client = SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect('ssh.example.com')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls -l; sleep 10; ls -l')
for line in stdout.readlines():
  print line
for line in stderr.readlines():
  print line
```

This seems to output new lines only at the end when the entire command has been finished. I'd like to receive the characters as they are generated by the remote commands. Is this possible?

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/6203877/3270800

Answer (score 0):

## To read the output on your terminal, the method i knew is to stream the readbinaries and writebinaries straight from the ssh session into your terminal

```
import paramiko
import os
import sys

host_address = ''
USER = ''
PASSWORD = ''

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(host_address, user=USER, password=PASSWORD)

#Time to invoke the shell from paramiko support
client_shell = client.INVOKE_SHELL()
standard_input = client_shell.makefile('wb')
standard_output = client_shell.makefile('rb')

standard_input.write('''
ls -l
sleep 10
ls -l
''')
print standard_output.read()

#Close all the streams and ssh connection in the end to flush the session

standard_input.close()
standard_output.close()
client.close()
```